# Show that $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb C \in 2\pi\mathrm i \mathbb Z$ when $L : \mathbb C\setminus\{0\} \to \mathbb C$ is continuous

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, continuity

### The Claim

Let $L : \mathbb C\setminus\{0\} \to \mathbb C$ be a continuous function and define $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb C, t \mapsto  L(\mathrm e ^{\mathrm i t}) - \mathrm i t$. Show that $f \in 2\pi \mathrm i \mathbb Z$ for all $t \in \mathbb R$.

### The beginnings of a proof

Let  $\varepsilon > 0$ and $a = \mathrm i 2\pi m$, where $m \in \mathbb Z$.
Then following from the continuity of $L$ and $-\mathrm i t$ (since $-\mathrm i t$ is a polynomial), as long as we choose $\delta > 0$ so that both $|L(t) - L(a)| < \varepsilon$ and $|-\mathrm i t + \mathrm i a| < \varepsilon$, we can write
\begin{align}
|f(t) - f(a)|
&= |L(\mathrm e ^{\mathrm i t}) - \mathrm i t - ( L(\mathrm e ^ {\mathrm i (\mathrm i 2\pi m)}) - \mathrm i (\mathrm i 2 \pi m))|\\
&= |L(\mathrm e ^{\mathrm i t}) - L(\mathrm e ^ {- 2\pi m} ) -  \mathrm i t \mathrm  - 2 \pi m|\\
&\leq |L(\mathrm e ^{\mathrm i t}) - L(\mathrm e ^ {- 2\pi m} )| + | -  \mathrm i t \mathrm  - 2 \pi m|\\
&\quad\vdots\\
&< 2\varepsilon,
\end{align}
which would prove the  claim. I'm just stuck at the three dots, and not even sure if I should be using the triangle inequality in this case.

Any hints?

### An edit and a disclaimer

What I'm actually supposed to be proving is that there is no such continuous function $L$ for which the equation $\mathrm e^{L(z)}=z$ holds.

I'm being told I should assume the opposite, show that the claim in this post holds and deduce, that as a result $f$ would have to be constant using Bolzano's theorem. This should result in a contradiction because of the fact, that $f(t+2π)=f(t)$ for all $t\in \mathbb R$.

### Edit number 2

I've just realized that it couldn't possibly be that $a \in \mathrm i 2 \pi \mathbb Z$ (at least not if I want the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof above to work), since $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$. I wonder if our lecturer made a typo in ths case.

Comment: The statement to be proved is false, note that $f(\pi)=-1-i\pi\notin 2\pi i\Bbb Z$. What is the relation between $L$ and $f$?

Comment: Hmm. I'm supposed to be proving this as a part of a larger proof, and might have misunderstood the hints given in the assignment. Let me do a little edit.

Comment: There. I made a mistake in copying my own notes. The function $f$ is defined as $t \mapsto L(\mathrm e^{\mathrm i t}) - \mathrm i t$.

Comment: One example of a continuous function is $L(z)=0$.  Your claim fails for this $L$.  So I guess you are missing some other hypotheses.